# How do you go over 512MB of memory in an Android app?

Tags: android, memory, out-of-memory

I'm developing an Android app that caches large images/gifs in memory to improve performance.
For some weaker devices, it is acceptable to limit the memory usage to 512MB. However, in devices (such as my own) that have 8GB and more of total memory available, it should be completely reasonable to use much more memory than that - 2GB and more.
However, Android seems to hard cap on 512MB:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24 byte allocation with 11219200 free bytes and 10MB until OOM, target footprint 536870912, growth limit 536870912; failed due to fragmentation (largest possible contiguous allocation 0 bytes). Number of 256KB sized free regions are: 0

It throws an out of memory error whenever used memory exceeds 512MB. This is with `android:largeHeap="true"` enabled.

How can I go over this limit?

Answer (score 0):

> However, in devices (such as my own) that have 8GB and more of total memory available, it should be completely reasonable to use much more memory than that - 2GB and more.

Users may disagree with you, when you wind up causing more of their other apps to have their processes terminated prematurely to free up system RAM for you.

> However, Android seems to hard cap on 512MB

The heap limits are set by the manufacturer, based on the available RAM and other considerations.

> How can I go over this limit?

Learn C/C++ and use the NDK. The heap limit is for allocations made by the runtime environment (Dalvik or ART) for apps using that runtime (Java/Kotlin/other JVM languages). Native allocations do not count against the heap limit.

Comment: @FudgeFudge I'd just also note here-  512MB is pretty reasonable.  I know devices in the last 5 years that capped around 100MB.  I wouldn't assume you have even 500MB available.  I suggest that if you're memory caching for perf reasons you look at a disk cache (or a 2 layer memory->disk LRU cache) rather than just an in memory cache.

Comment: The unreasonable part is that Google expects developers to work with high resolution video and images within the limit, while discouraging ndk use.